# phpmyadmin: query to search/replace term

Tags: mysql, database, search, replace, phpmyadmin

I have a table named `wp_posts` and a column named `post_content`.

Within this table, I want to search through every entry of `post_content` and find all instances of `<em>` and replace it with `<em class="title">`.

How can I do this using **phpmyadmin**? I have 50,000+ rows in this table so the query should ideally not crash my server.

Comment: Have you tried googling for 'mysql replace' ?

Comment: Yes, I found a few variation of queries, but none detailing which is best to use in large tables as such.

Comment: what you are looking is a replace function

Comment: There's not a lot of difference between a one-time update of 10 rows and a one-time update of 50,000 rows.  MySQL doesn't provide a BETTER_UPDATE command to use in this case.  50,000 is a small table (about the number of zip codes in the U.S.).

Comment: Each post_content contains at least 1000 words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with SQL:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '<em>', '<em class=\"title\">');
```

Comment: How will this query be on my server given that there are over 50,000 rows in this table, and every post_content contains at least 1000 words...

Comment: thats almost the only way you can modify the data. you have to use SQL to do it. But I can't tell you how long it will take to run this query. But 50000 rows is not that much for a database...